# Admin level user denied access to S3 objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm really struggling to gain access to objects in an S3 bucket.
Things I've done:

1. IAM user has admin level privileges already
2. Granted AmazonS3FullAccess
3. Set the bucket policy to public allowed get...

   ```
   {
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Principal": "*",
           "Action": "s3:GetObject",
           "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::images.bucketname.com/*"
       }
   ]
   ```

   }

I don't want get to be public but I'm just trying to get this to work right now. I had set up a new IAM user for the application itself that will fetch objects as the principal but again, for some reason that didn't work.

4. I'm uploading the images with `putObject`in Node.

Am I missing something here because I'm getting full access denied to everything in S3. I can't open an image even logged in as the root user. I can't download an object. There is no viable way for me to view the images I'm uploading.

All of these buttons within the console either throw a blank error or route to the standard AWS access denied XML page.

[image]

On the other hand I can successfully, programmatically, upload files to the bucket using the root users credentials.

What am I missing here? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you the owner of the objects? See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example3.html.

Comment: Yes, I am the owner

Comment: Are the objects KMS-encrypted? What ACL are you indicating when calling putObject? Have you modified the default ACLs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html)?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe that's it. Let me try setting the ACL on upload

Comment: @PhilAndrews how did you upload the objects in question?  You might *not* own them under just the wrong conditions -- they can have no owner.  Easy test is to try to delete one of them, which still works if it's your bucket but not your object.  (If uploaded through the console, this wouldn't happen.)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You're saying try to programmatically delete something, or try and delete from the console?

Comment: If an object exists in your bucket that you don't own, you delete it programmatically or via the console, unless a separate IAM or bucket policy prevents you from doing so.  That is one way to test the theory that the problem is really that you don't own the object (even if you think you should).  Alternately, `aws s3api list-objects` with the `--output text` option may prove informative, since it shows you the owner of each object.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to *access* the bucket for some MVP or hobby project and you **don't** care about security then I would recommend you switch off the default settings of the bucket here:

[image]

**To re-iterate, only do this in development as it may not be recommended for production**